# Difference between smoke and vapor in sealed space

Tags: evaporation

I got a questions. I've got a sphere that has only one hole on the bottom. I tried it out and inside of the sphere, fire is extinguished instantly (it does not even enter the sphere through the hole).

Now I saw a light bulb vaporizer that is completely sealed where herbs are heated up with a fire. I don't understand how the vapor can be created in this sealed light bulb without fresh air coming in.

Here is the video that I am referring to:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A7vtNTX4lwQ

Any help would be greatly appreciated!